# Weather Icons Font

Tags: java, android, fonts

I'm creating a weather application using an api and from the json object I'm getting

> {"success":true,"temp":"14","picto":"meteo_32","icon":"\uf00d;","unite":"C","frequence":"4"}

I used for the font of the picture :

> https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/

So I added the strings to the directory of the project in android studio and this is my code :

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(responseContent);
String icon = String.valueOf(jObj.get("icon"));
weatherFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/weathericons_regular_webfont.ttf");
imageMTO.setTypeface(
icon = icon.replace("\\u", "&#x");
imageMTO.setText(icon);
```

But I'm getting &#xuf00d; on the textView when I run the app

Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
icon = icon.replace("\\u", "&#x");
```

this line make you a problem

Actually it should work fine with `\uf00d`
Use
.replace(";", "");

Comment: even if I don't use it nothing change

Comment: Please describe why is this line a problem and what's the solution.

Comment: It crash saying java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "\uf00d;"

Comment: Non ça n'a pas marché

Answer (score 0):

am not really 100 percent sure but i think it is because in your json object icon is **uf00d**